# ListView throws NULL Pointer exception

Tags: android, android-listview, nullpointerexception

read a lot of the questions about NPE's.. still in the dark.

I declare a listview :

```
public class SelecteerKernen extends Activity {


protected WoordData kerndata;
public ListView listView = null;
```

Later, I fill it with data from a SQLite dBase. This works.

```
// Fill Listview with the kern-names        
    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.kernenlist);
    listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, al));
```

But then, when I want to count the items, to save the checked items to preferences, I get a NPE on the int count = ... line of this code .

Edit I solved the count.. line, now the if (this.listView)... line throws the NPE.. Argh! :

```
    private String getSavedItems() {
    String savedItems = "";

    int count = this.listView.getAdapter().getCount();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

    //edit now THIS line trows the NPE :
            if (this.listView.isItemChecked(i)) {

            if (savedItems.length() > 0) {
                savedItems += "," + this.listView.getItemAtPosition(i);
            } else {
                savedItems += this.listView.getItemAtPosition(i);
            }
        }

    }
    return savedItems;
```

Thanks for the help!!

---

PS. I noticed that users are asked for LogCats. How can that help to find the error? Here's mine :

> 11-01 19:42:35.680: W/dalvikvm(28146): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
>   11-01 19:42:35.700: E/AndroidRuntime(28146): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   11-01 19:42:35.700: E/AndroidRuntime(28146): java.lang.NullPointerException
>   11-01 19:42:35.700: E/AndroidRuntime(28146):    at happyworx.nl.Flitswoorden.SelecteerKernen.getSavedItems(SelecteerKernen.java:163)
>   11-01 19:42:35.700: E/AndroidRuntime(28146):    at happyworx.nl.Flitswoorden.SelecteerKernen.SavePreferences(SelecteerKernen.java:121)
>   11-01 19:42:35.700: E/AndroidRuntime(28146):    at happyworx.nl.Flitswoorden.SelecteerKernen.access$0(SelecteerKernen.java:115)
>   11-01 19:42:35.700: E/AndroidRuntime(28146):    at happyworx.nl.Flitswoorden.SelecteerKernen$1.onClick(SelecteerKernen.java:72)
>   ...

Comment: I solved this by adding `public ListAdapter la = null;` and defining the adapter like this : `la = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, al);
        listView.setAdapter(la);`.. But now, I'm getting the same error on the line `if (this.listView.isItemChecked(i)) {`.. guess that's what happens if you Google a lot and solve errors without actually knowing what the cause is ;) :-S.

Comment: Oh.. and I changed the count from `listview.getadapter().count()` to `int count = la.getCount();`.. So I'm actually not solving the problem, but counting the arrayitems instead of the listview items. And thusly moving the problem to the next line that relies on the listview() thingie.

Comment: Pondering.. is it because the class extends Activity instead of ListActivity? But.. if I change that, I get into the part where I have to change /@id+ to android:id in the XML, and add android.R to imports.. I've tried that.. it was HORROR..

Comment: Woooops! So.. I changed the
`ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.kernenlist);`

to

`this.listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.kernenlist);`

AND IT WORKS! Thanks @Eelco de Vries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Woooops! So.. I changed the line

`ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.kernenlist);`

to

`this.listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.kernenlist);`

..And now it works! :)

Appearantly, by using the first line, I declared a new, local variable, leaving the public variable at NULL ?? Not sure, maybe you can comment on this?

Comment: With the first line, you create a local variable named listview, like the global variable. This variable is created only for the time your method is working. Therefore, it is then destroyed. As you stated, you should use your global variable instead, using `this.listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.kernenlist);` or simply `this.listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.kernenlist);`